# What does $\mathcal{C}^{1}$ mean?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, notation

- 11.15 Theorem. Let $V$ be open in $\mathbf{R}^{n},$ let a $\in V,$ and suppose that $\mathbf{f} : V \rightarrow \mathbf{R}^{m}$ .
  If all first-order partial derivatives of $\mathbf f$ exist in $V$ and are continuous at $a$, then $\mathbf{f}$ is differentiable at a.

NOTE: These hypotheses are met if $\mathbf f$ is $\mathcal{C}^{1}$ on $V$

The paragraph is from Wade's *Introduction to Analysis*, p.398

**My question:** What does $\mathcal{C}^{1}$ mean? Is that complex set?

Comment: $f\in C^n(X)$ means that all the $n$th-order partial derivatives exist and are continuous at each point of $X$.

Comment: Or at least, it is $n$ times continuously differentiable, which is not exactly the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of the $c$ in $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3217920/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-c-in-c-c-infty-mathbbr)

Comment: As an additional bit of advice, many authors include an index of notation, or include their notations in the general index.  If you get stuck, that is a good first place to look.

Answer (score 1):

Well as it states above, it is a set of classes of functions such that they are partial differentiable and all the partial derivatives are continuous. 
So basically any function that is of class C1 can be used with the chain rule.